# Newly created Amazon EC2 ubuntu server - can not log in through amazon java client

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ssh-keys

I have been using AWS for a while now without issues but wanted a new basic web server so started a new simple Ubuntu image.

It all goes through fine - I set up port access (ssh:22) etc... Use my key pair that is working on a different image - or create a new key pair (still does not work in next step).

Then I start the java client (that amazon provides) to ssh connect to the new server, normally this goes through fine in the past. But now it keeps booting me out saying:

Authentication failed, permission denied.

Using username Ubuntu... This is a brand new image?! Is their something silly im forgetting?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never liked MindTerm (the java client). If you are a windows user try [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) instead (you will have to [convert your keys](http://sshcontrol.com/help/puttygen_keys) using puttygen). 
If you are using Linux, just use ssh from the console.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped - as it helped me understand the .pem file

It seems [this link explains](http://omgili.com/thread/.wHSUbtEfZRWdzjE8MP1_Xnn7dSEzcXkUIwegllDOCHHTfrhQspQBRrvhEEgrer11T5wv0FOafuRuL7r2ydXdstEJbzc6YgN/) MindTerm was messing up on my machine - that link explains that the default place it looks for the .pem file may be different to where you think it is looking for it.